# Return JSON wrapped in a callback function from a WCF REST web service

Tags: .net, wcf, json, callback, jsonp

I have a web service returning JSON, but now I'd like to modify it to allow callers to specify a callback function so the return goes from: JSON DATA to specifiedFunction(JSON DATA); The way I'm returning JSON right now is just by returning an instance of an object and having .NET do its serialization magic, if I change to just returning a string I can add the name of the function and the brackets around the data but then I end up with quotation marks in the return, because its a string and I don't want those. So how can I go about it?

Reason for this is we want developers calling our API to be able to use the dynamic script tag as explained here http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2005/12/21/json-dynamic-script-tag.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The technique you are after is called [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP) (JSON with Padding).

See [How to support JSONP in WCF services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716898(loband).aspx):

> The `JsonPEncoder` is a wrapping encoder
>   on the WCF JSON encoder. It delegates
>   most calls to the wrapped encoder. The
>   `WriteMesage` methods have been
>   overriden to pad the outgoing message
>   with the callback method. The
>   `JsonBehavior` is used on the service
>   operation to enable JSONP encoding for
>   that operation. The query parameter of
>   the URI that holds the callback
>   function name is specified as the
>   `CallBack` property of the behavior.

Comment: Wow. I'd heard of JSONP, but didn't know it sent the callback function name. Any links to which browsers support that src=expression syntax?

Answer (score 5):

In WCF 4.0 added support for JSONP. You may use

```
  <bindings>
    <webHttpBinding>
      <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
    </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
```

http://bendewey.wordpress.com/2009/11/24/using-jsonp-with-wcf-and-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what version of HTML they're using, but in all the versions that I've used, the src attribute in a script tag has to be a URL. They're somehow using a function instead, and I don't see that working.

Have you actually seen a dynamic script tag work?

Comment: I've not used it personally but as far as I know it can be done. There are examples of web services out there that return in the style I'm after, for example http://www.geonames.org/export/JSON-webservices.html

Comment: I'm not so concerned about these services as I am the browsers. Someone more up to date can correct me, but I don't expect anything other than a URL to work in the src attribute.

Comment: regardless, any help on how to format the return as required will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old thread, but it seems that everyone insists on changing the WCF to support JSONP when that's clearly not what the poster asked. And I posted here and forums.asp.net and nobody took the time to reply.

I ended up returning it as a stream. This causes the "raw" mode to be used and WCF will not touch the response. Link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2008/04/17/wcf-raw-programming-model-web.aspx.

Comment: I have been working on this problem since yesterday morning!! You and Carlos' blog post saved my rear! Thank you so much!!