# jQuery .ajax() function always returning error

Tags: jquery

Friends, I'm lost here.

I have this WCF Rest service returning data in json format: http://189.126.109.249/ieptb/Cidades?uf=SP

I can access it using a asp.net web form application and also, I can access it using a Windows Phone application. But I'm not getting to make it work under a simple jQuery.$Ajax() call. My jQuery is always returning an error. If you take a look into my code you will see I have a function for catching errors.

Here is the script I'm using: http://jsfiddle.net/n6sLQ/4/

I've tested with Fiddler, and it shows me that HTTP response is 200 (ok), even it shows me the json array returned, like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Via: 1.1 CM-SRV03
Connection: Keep-Alive
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 2360
Date: Tue, 29 Nov 2011 13:02:44 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Cache-Control: private

[{"Nome":"AGUAS DE LINDOIA","Uf":"SP"},{"Nome":"AMERICANA","Uf":"SP"},{"Nome":"AMPARO","Uf":"SP"}]
```

I dont know what is wrong with my jQuery...

```
  $.ajax({
            url: "http://189.126.109.249/ieptb/Cidades?uf=SP",
contentType:"application/json",
            dataType: "json",

            error: function (x, e) {
                if (x.status === 0) {
                    alert('You are offline!!\n Please Check Your Network. ' + x.reponseText);
                }
                else if (x.status == 404) {
                    alert('Requested URL not found.');
                } else if (x.status == 500) {
                    alert('Internel Server Error.');
                } else if (e == 'parsererror') {
                    alert('Error.\nParsing JSON Request failed.');
                } else if (e == 'timeout') {
                    alert('Request Time out.');
                } else {
                    alert('Unknow Error.\n' + x.responseText);
                }
            },
            success: function (cidades) {

               // $.each(cidades, function (indice, cidade) {
               //     alert(cidade.Nome + ": " + cidade.Uf);
               // });
            }
                    });
```

Someone has some idea?

Comment: Remember that if the call is cross-domain you have to use jsonp!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is cross-side scripting. This can easily fixed by using `'jsonp'` as dataType.
And then changing the website to use the '"?callback=' that has been added to the call and wrap that around the json. For example if `callback = 'test'`

```
test('[{"Nome":"AGUAS DE LINDOIA","Uf":"SP"},{"Nome":"AMERICANA","Uf":"SP"},{"Nome":"AMPARO","Uf":"SP"}]')
```

Comment: Friends, really thank you! As I'm using WCF 4 I just had to change my web.config to accept cross-side ( [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178614/return-json-wrapped-in-a-callback-function-from-a-wcf-rest-web-service[/link] ), and of course, make use of jsonp. Again, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Link for the description](http://www.maheshchari.com/jquery-ajax-error-handling/)
`status === 0` - xhr status ,is it initialized or not that means **user** is offline.

You'll see a status of 0 when either doing **cross-site** scripting (where access is denied) or requesting a URL that is unreachable (typo, DNS issues, etc).

Comment: The user has to use JSONP indeed. Basicly this is wrapping the returned JSON in a function call way.